# Sorting of data in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySql. I am working on a query to find all the products of each customer in descending order on the basis of their sum(amount).

This is my query:

```
SELECT customer_name, item_code, sum(item_amount) AS Amount 
FROM `table1` 
WHERE site='Mum' AND 
      item_code like 'FG%' AND 
      invoice_type='Excise' 
GROUP BY customer_name,item_code
order by customer_name,item_code,Amount DESC
```

Comment: you are near to it, just put amount first in order by to set it as primary sorting cokumn

Comment: `order by Amount, customer_name,item_code DESC `

Comment: show your sample output

Comment: The problem is not on the `ORDER BY` clause. The query attempts to select both the list of products and the sum of their amounts which is not possible in a single query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select * from (SELECT 
    customer_name, item_code, sum(item_amount) AS Amount 
FROM `table1` 
WHERE site='Mum' 
    and item_code like 'FG%' 
    and invoice_type='Excise' 
group by customer_name,item_code 
order by customer_name,item_code) as t order by t.Amount desc
```

Comment: You should include more information on how this query helps the OP.

Comment: @Wtower OP had already shows his query. so am only added how to sort by that particular column.

Answer (score 1):

Your query creates one group for each pair (`customer_name`, `item_code`) and computes `SUM(item_amount)` for all the records from such a group. If you don't have different products having the same `item_code` (you shouldn't), each such group contain a single product and `SUM(item_amount)` is equal to `item_amount`.

I understand this is not what you want. You want to compute `SUM(item_amount)` using all the products bought by a customer. This requires grouping by `customer_name` only. But in this case you cannot get the list of products.

#### A solution

A simple solution to your problem is to run two queries; the first query gets the list of customers, sorted descending by the total amount they spent. The second query gets the products bought by these customers.
The first query looks like the one you already wrote, it only skips using the field `item_code` (to get `SUM(item_amount)`) for all products of a customer:

```
SELECT customer_name, sum(item_amount) AS Amount 
FROM `table1` 
WHERE site='Mum' AND 
      item_code like 'FG%' AND 
      invoice_type='Excise' 
GROUP BY customer_name
ORDER BY Amount DESC
```

The second query is generated in the client application using the values of `customer_name` returned by the first query:

```
SELECT customer_name, item_code
FROM `table`
WHERE customer_name IN (...)   # <--- put the list of names here
```

Additional code in the application is needed to combine the two lists.

#### Remarks

I hope the table has an index on column `customer_name`. If if doesn't then add it.

#### Another possible solution (I didn't test it)

```
SELECT t1.customer_name, t1.item_code, t2.Amount
FROM `table1` t1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT customer_name, sum(item_amount) AS Amount 
    FROM `table1` 
    WHERE site='Mum' AND 
          item_code like 'FG%' AND 
          invoice_type='Excise' 
    GROUP BY customer_name
  ) t2 ON t1.customer_name = t2.customer_name
ORDER BY t2.Amount DESC, t1.customer_name
```

It combines the two queries above in a single query. Its performance is theoretically worse than of the two queries above. However, if the `WHERE` condition selects a small number of rows then the overall processing time is probably smaller than for the other answer (where additional processing is required in the application).